# Magento Error when Accessing User Roles Section

Tags: php, magento, user-roles

I have a Magento site in which there are about 20-25 extensions installed, among which 7 are commercial, which means that those 7 extensions are fully encrypted. Also none of these extensions use the User Roles & Permissions section, in the Admin area.

Now, a few days back, I got into a silly problem which is really taking a toll on me. I wanted to create a new User Role (from System > Permissions > Roles), where I already have 14 other Roles set. Now whenever I click the "Add New Role" button or try to edit any of the existing roles, I get the following error:-

```
<my-magento-site-domain>: This script is locked to another domain.
```

What I'm pretty sure is that this error is somewhere related to the use of extensions, but I don't know & can't understand where it is coming from. I have tried to solve this error by disabling all the extensions & clearing the full cache & deleting all the folders in the "/var/" folder, but nothing has happened.

Magento version: **1.3.2.3**
I know that Magento upgradation is necessary, but can't do so due to those extensions.

Can somebody please help me in this matter? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say that you disabled all the extensions, how did you perform that step?  I've found that the `System>Config>Advanced` status values are often ignored by extensions, as are various other attempts to disable.  The only way that you can be certain of disabling the extension (IMHO) is to remove their .xml files from `etc/modules`.

It sounds like the error that you are getting is a Javascript generated error.  You could grep the `/js` folder to find that error text to see if you can track down the source of the error.  Likewise, use Firebug (or Chrome Inspector, choose your browser poison) to debug the JS error.  Post what you find here...

One more option is to manually create the new role using phpmyadmin.  By inspecting the admin_role table, you'll work out the syntax fairly quickly (e.g. `tree_level` ="1", `role_type` = "G".  Then see if you can edit the new role through the UI.

Cheers,
JD

Comment: About disabling the extensions from "System > Configuration > Advanced" section, the modules which are disabled from here are meant for disabling the UI part of these modules only. Internally the modules are still active. And yes, you are right, we need to delete the XML files from "/app/etc/modules" folder.

Comment: I found the error in two of my commercial extensions, and disabling them did the trick. So many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know that using the web UI for disabling extensions only disables the UI aspects.  I didn't know that, and I guess it makes sense in an obscure, Magento-type way :) 

Pleased that it worked out for you.
JD

Answer (score 1):

You can try with clean magento install without commercial extensions. Add a role and see if this happens. Then add commercial extensions one by one and test when this error occurs.

I assume that you have already searched all magento files (at least non encrypted ones) to see if there is any containing your error message...